# Multiple controllers with a single model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm setting up a directory application for which I need to have two separate interfaces for the same Users table.  Basically, administrators use the Users controller and views to list, edit, and add users, while non-admins need a separate interface which lists users in a completely different manner.  To do this, would I be able to just set up another controller with different views but which accesses the Users model?

Sorry if this is a simple question, but I've had a hard time finding how to do this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not put the admin part into a separate namespace - you would have `Admin::UsersController` with views in `app/views/admin/users/`. And your users would go to `UsersController` with its own views in `app/views/users/`.

The routing is defined like this:

```
map.namespace :admin do |admin|
  admin.resources :users
end


map.resources :users
```

And can be got to via `admin_users_path` and `users_path`

Comment: I had read about namespaces, but I was concerned that using them would conflict with my nested resources.  Is that not the case?

Comment: @Eric: No, that's not the case at all. I'll expand the original answer.